# how to solve problem with JWT authorization in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jwt, authorization

what a problem, I have such an authorization on the asp.net server, registration returns a generated JWT token, I try to enter it in Postman, but I get a 405 error, I don’t know what I’m doing wrong

i.e. when I register, I get a new token, and when I use it in Postman and make some kind of request, I get 405

My login controller

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("account")]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<AccountController> _logger;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signinManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            ILogger<AccountController> logger,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signinManager,
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _signinManager = signinManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel userLogin)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid || userLogin == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Invalid login object provided.");
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userLogin.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("email", "Login or password error");
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var signInResult = await _signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userLogin.Email, userLogin.Password, true, false);
            if (!signInResult.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Unable to sign-in findUser {userLogin.Email}.");
                return Unauthorized();
            }
            _logger.LogInformation($"User {userLogin.Email} logged in successfully.");
            var claims = new[]
               {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userLogin.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Authentication:JWT:SecurityKey"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _configuration["Authentication:JWT:Issuer"],
                _configuration["Authentication:JWT:Audience"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                signingCredentials: creds
            );

            var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

            return Ok(new { AccessToken = tokenString });
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterViewModel userRegister)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid || userRegister == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Invalid login object provided.");
                return BadRequest();
            }
            try
            {
                var findUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userRegister.Email);
                if (findUser != null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username is already used");
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e.Message);
            };

            var user = new IdentityUser
            {
                Email = userRegister.Email,
                UserName = userRegister.Email,
            };

            try
            {
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userRegister.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("{Email} created", user.Email);
                     await _signinManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                    _logger.LogInformation("{Email} login", user.Email);

                    var claims = new[]
                    {
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userRegister.Email),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, user.Id)
                    };
                    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Authentication:JWT:SecurityKey"]));
                    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: _configuration["Authentication:JWT:Issuer"],
                        audience: _configuration["Authentication:JWT:Audience"],
                        claims,
                        expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                        signingCredentials: creds
                    );

                    var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
                    return Ok(new { AccessToken = tokenString });
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Create account errors: {Errors}",result.Errors.Select(s => s.Description));
                    return BadRequest(string.Join(", ", result.Errors.Select(s => s.Description)));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e.Message);
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Program.cs connecting jwt

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                        ValidIssuer = config["Authentication:JWT:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = config["Authentication:JWT:Audience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["Authentication:JWT:SecurityKey"]))
                    };
                });
            services.AddAuthorization();
```

Comment: There are different types of authentication method.  Recently a lot of sites are moving from Windows Authentication to OAUTH 2.0.  Not sure which method you server is using.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/651554/request-matched-endpoint-405-http-method-not-suppo?force_isolation=true

Comment: HTTP 405 means "Method not allowed", for example if you're using a GET verb on an endpoint that doesn't allow that verb.

Comment: @gunr2171 Im make GET request, use only POSTMAN bearer authorization, method not accept any data

Comment: @gunr2171 When i made my request to /api/todo (hi is private), the server redirects it to /account/login even though I add Bearer token in POSTMAN

Answer (score 1):

as gunr2171 stated, the error code you are getting, 405, is a method not allowed error. You are attempting to use a get (in Postman as you indicated) and your two endpoints are only setup to accept a POST.
These are the C# attributes you have in your code telling it to listen only for POST requests:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
[HttpPost("register")]
```

you are either going to want to change the `HttpPost` to `HttpGet` attributes or you want to make sure you use `POST` when testing in Postman.
For example:

```
[HttpGet("login")]
[HttpGet("register")]
```

Because both of your endpoints have `[AllowAnonymous]` neither of them should care about the BEARER header because callers to those endpoints are not required to authenticate themselves.

Comment: I make GET request to /api/todo, this is method only return all todos, he is need authorize, but my app redirect me to /account/login

Comment: so the issue is that you are not expecting to have to login when calling /api/todo because you are specifying an Authorization header with a bearer token in it?
If that is the case, you need to ensure that the value you are sending is a valid value for the JWT verification checks you have set. Are the issuer, audience, and signing keys you are using to generate the JWT the same as those in the config values?